# How private variables in superclass is inherited in the subclass here?

Tags: java

```
package practice;

class person{
private String firstname;
private String lastname;

public person(String firstname,String lastname){
    set_first(firstname);
    set_last(lastname);
}

public String get_first() {
    return firstname;
}
public void set_first(String firstname) {
    this.firstname=firstname;
}
public void set_last(String lastname) {
    this.lastname=lastname;
}
public String get_last() {
    return lastname;
}
}

class employee extends person{  
private int empid;  
public employee(String firstname,String lastname,int empid){  
    super(firstname,lastname);  
    set_empid(empid);
}

public void set_empid(int empid) {
    this.empid=empid;
}
public int get_empid() {
    return empid;
}
}

class testing_super_keyword {  
public static void main(String args[]) {  
    employee emp=new employee("John","Jackson",1234);  
    System.out.println(emp.get_first()+"  "+emp.get_last());  
    System.out.println(emp.get_empid());  
}
}
```

Can anybody explain how the class employee inheriting the class person even when the attributes of the class person "firstname" and "lastname"have been declared as private?

AS of my knowledge a superclass variable declared as private cant be inherited by the sub class.

Answer (score 1):

This is a considered a good programming practice where you do not give direct access to the instance variables of a class by using `private access specifiers` and instead provide the `public getter and setter methods` to get and set the instance variables.

In you case you cannot access the instance variables of SuperClass directly but you have the `public getter and setter methods(get_first, set_first)` declared and you can make use of them.

Also, as per the Java naming convention use the camelCase names for functions. For example instead of get_name use getName and son on.